# I am wondering why this code would produce 2

Tags: c

I don't know if anyone could kindly explain this code for me?

```
unsigned int x = 0;
(x ^= x ) || x++ || ++x || x++;

printf("%d\n", x);
```

when I compile this on my computer using gcc 4.2, the output is 2.

Originally i thought maybe this behavior is unspecified but then i figure || will have lower precedence over other operators, so shouldn't the answer be 3? Since there are three "++".

Can someone explain? Thanks

Comment: it isn't the precedence of `||` that matters, so much as the fact that it's a sequence point.

Comment: The behavior is perfectly specified (unlike similar questions periodically asked here).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `(x ^= x)` is evaluated and it yields 0, therefore:
- `(x++)` is evaluated and it **yields 0**, therefore:
- `(++x)` is evaluated and it yields 2, therefore **it stops**

It all boils down to one rule: `||` only evaluates its right side if its left side is false.

Comment: Rats! You're right. I was looking at it overflowing a 32bit int and then adding 3 to it (which would also produce 2) but your answer is correct.

Comment: @PeterRowell That's quite interesting, I didn't think so far :-)

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that the `||` operator is short-circuiting.  As soon as it finds a true value, it no longer needs to check the remaining `||` statements; the answer is already known.

`(x ^= x)` evaluates to 0.
`x++` evaluates to 0, then increments `x` to 1.
`++x` evaluates to 2 -- true.

The final or statement does not need to be computed.  It "short-circuits" and immediately returns true.

Comment: This is the correct answer it seems, the others forget to explain the ++ operator taking effect after the evaluation of that part of the expression.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour is well-defined. You are observing the short-circuiting behaviour of ||; the final x++ is never evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

That is short-circuit semantics in action. The first expression `x ^= x` evaluates to `0`, the second evaluates to `0` as well. The third one evaluates to `2`, and then the logical expression is short-circuited since its result its already determined to be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The expressions between the `||` operators will be evaluated left to right until one is `true`:

```
(x ^= x )
```

Sets all bits in `x` to 0/off. (`false`);

```
x++
```

Increments `x`, it's now `1`, but still `false` because this was a post increment.

```
++x
```

(pre-)Increments `x`, which is now `2` and also `true`, so there is no need for the right hand side of `||` to be evaluated.

Comment: You must be sleepy, 0 XOR 0 does not evaluate to 1, even if you have 11.8k points :)

Comment: @owlstead - I initially misread the code. I thought I'd edited that mistake out. Did I miss one?

Comment: I'm reading something different now, so I wrote the comment while it was being updated (the submit was 2 min. after your edit, it seems).

Answer (score 0):

Of course you shouldn't use such constructs, but let us analyze the expression.

There are 4 expressions combined with shortcut-OR:

```
a || b || c || d
```

b, c and d are only evaluated, if a is false, c and d only if b is false too, and d only if all from the before are false.

Ints are evaluated as 0 == false, everything else is not false.

```
x ^= 0
```

with x being 0 is 0 again.

```
x++
```

is evaluated and later increased, so it evaluates to 0, which invokes expression c, but later x will be increased.

```
++x
```

is first incremented, leading to 1, and then evaluated (leading to 1) which is the reason, why d is not evaluated, but the increment of b is pending, so we get 2.

But I'm not sure, whether such behaviour is exactly defined and leads to the same result on all compilers.

```
Avoid it.
```